# Reading "Settings" application data inside my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uidevice

How can I read "Settings" application data inside my iPhone application?

I wanted to read some of my application settings from there.

Answer (score 0):

[NSUserDefaults](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/): [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I wanted to read the push notification flags set for my app (in the Settings application) inside my app.

Answer (score 0):

to save:
self.data is your data, I've NSDictionary as datatype for this.

```
    -(void)saveData{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:self.data forKey:@"data"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

to get data back.

```
self.data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
                     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"data"]
                     ];
```

Comment: I wanted to read the push notification flags set for my app (in the Settings application) inside my app.